# Countless "Could not find class" errors in logcat suddenly

Tags: android, logcat

I am getting an absolute ton of these errors in my log, which makes it really hard to find my own output. The app doesn't crash, everything is running, I just don't understand why all these error messages are popping up.

Some of the errors are coming from my own classes, complaining about "android.os.PersistableBundle", but I am not using that class anywhere, and the rest of it is coming from the SlidingTabLayout and SlidingTabStrip by Google themselves.

My minSDK is 18, and my activity is an AppCompatActivity. The code for SlidingTabStrip and SlidingTabLayout can be found here: https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget .

I don't know which of my 2.000 lines of code could be making these errors appear, but they only appear on my Android 4.4.4 device, not my Android 5.1.1 device.

```
09-03 19:23:32.428 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.437 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.439 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.447 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.455 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.465 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.467 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.485 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.503 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.508 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:32.516 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.Splash.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.089 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.095 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.097 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.098 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.106 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.118 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.120 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.130 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.138 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.141 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.146 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.myapp.MainActivity.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.201 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewOutlineProvider', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.203 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.207 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.214 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.239 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnContextClickListener', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.247 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.253 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.258 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.265 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.266 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.274 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabLayout.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.315 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewOutlineProvider', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.317 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.321 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.328 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.334 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnContextClickListener', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.341 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.346 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.352 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.358 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.360 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.366 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.myapp.SlidingTabStrip.access$super
09-03 19:23:34.411 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
09-03 19:23:34.455 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback', referenced from method com.myapp.BluetoothService.access$1000
09-03 19:23:34.457 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner', referenced from method com.myapp.BluetoothService.access$1100
09-03 19:23:34.458 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings', referenced from method com.myapp.BluetoothService.access$900
09-03 19:23:34.481 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.myapp.BluetoothService$5', referenced from method com.myapp.BluetoothService.initScanCallback
09-03 19:23:34.734 8273-8273/com.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
```

Comment: Add your code..

Comment: My minSDK is 18, and my activity is a AppCompatActivity. The code for SlidingTabStrip and SlidingTabLayout can be found here: https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget .

I don't know which of my 2.000 lines of code could make these errors appear, but they only appear on my Android 4.4.4 device, not my Android 5.1.1 device.

Comment: Huge...... m not gonna touch that. Sorry.

Comment: I know, it is a mess, I just hoped somebody had experienced the same issue, since it seems like a thing that could be easily fixed. Nothing is "wrong", nothing is crashing. I just get an incredible amount of "useless" output, for reasons I am oblivious to.